# Paypal sdk asp.net return (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to use **Paypal** for payment with **credit card** on my website that in **asp.net mvc** but every time I face a problem that it return with exception

> (400) Bad Request.

so I tried to use the samples [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/) 
specially the sample of *PaymentWithCreditCard* and it work very well but when I try to change the **web.config** with my **clientId** and **clientSecret** I get the same error !!

I'm sure I wrote my client id and secret code right on both my code and sample, but don't know why I get this error!!

sample work well with it's client id and secret,, but give me this error when I use my client id and secret id

and that the details of the error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> name: "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
>
> message: An unknown error has occurred
>
> information_link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR
>
> debug_id: 7f3c48e317bbb

hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you please post a relevant part of your code for analysis?

Comment: Is this on live or sandbox?  If it's on sandbox, what credit card number are you testing with?  Have you tried a different credit card?

Comment: it's exactly the same code [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Samples/Source/PaymentWithCreditCard.aspx.cs)

Comment: @JasonZ it's sandbox and I tried with 2 visa card on the buyer account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sandbox account doesn't seem to be pro . I just reactivated the pro on it . It should be fine now if you try to process a card payment .

Comment: I was already reactivate it to pro, but it still didn't work .. but now and without any changing with the code it worked!! incredible